# Mines and Quarries Happiness effects

Tags: banished

Trying to find out some information about the Mines and Quarries Happiness debuff effect.

I know it's been said that they effect near by houses, but what is the actual radius? Has anyone been able to test this?

Also, is it only houses that are nearby or is it anywhere that people spend a decent amount of time at?

I have a mine and a quarry fairly close together and the people are pretty miserable, but that seems like it might be spreading to a nearby Fishing Dock and possibly as far as my closest Forester Cluster.

Earlier in the game I had an Orchard(4 workers) next to the Quarry and my overall town happiness was a little low, but I ended up moving the Orchard to the other side of town when I started creating a designated farming area and my overall happiness is back up. Not sure how connect that is though.

Comment: I thought the unhappiness was just on the people themselves not on an area around the building, but I may be reading this wrong? Its hard to track things like this at times when the villagers just seem to like to swap jobs when they feel like it.

Answer (score 1):

I know that [some wiki's](http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Citizens) tend to say that it will decrease your happiness. But in fact, I haven't noticed something like these. Even after many in-game centuries.

It *may* occur that your happiness will lower, if you build many quarries. But I would think that this could have many causes. If your people had longer walks to the quarry or their houses run out of firewood or food. All this could lower your happiness. It is also common to place the quarry outside the city (due to his nature), as he will leave a whole in the landscape after he's finished. In fact, this building principle can lower your happiness to, as you won't build a tavern, school and maybe even a marketplace near to it.

I normally build a quarry near a market place and near the houses of each worker. Additionally I provide structures like a brewery and things like that. My workers normally tend to have a 5 star rating over many years. Even if they continuously working in the quarry or mine.

As I could see, there is no *real* or *big* impact of quarries/mines and happiness. It may be a side effect but in fact I haven't seen any relation to it.